# SwiftUI doesn't use auto layout, how to create a unique size interface for all devices?

Tags: ios, swiftui, autolayout, widget

I don't use SwiftUI before and try to create the medium widget but I can't recreate the copy of this widget from another program(YouTube Music medium widget), my fourth cells on different screens have a different edge margin, I don't know how to fix this margins because SwiftUI doesn't have auto layout. I posted the code of my widget below, if somebody knows what I did wrong correct me, please.

Screenshot of my Widget and widget What I want:
[image]

Code of my widget:

```
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import Intents
import Foundation

struct Provider: IntentTimelineProvider {
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {...}

    func getSnapshot(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {...}

    func getTimeline(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {...}
}

struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {...}


struct WidgetTestEntryView : View {
    
    var entry: Provider.Entry
    
    var deeplinkURLFirst: URL {
        URL(string: "\(WIDGET_DEEP_LINK)0")!
    }
    
    let iconSize: CGFloat = 75.0
    var widgetLabel = "Favourites"
    let mainColor = Color(red: 0.218, green: 0.215, blue: 0.25)
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            GeometryReader { geo in
                HStack(spacing: geo.size.width * 0.4){
                    Text(widgetLabel).foregroundColor(.white).font(.system(size: geo.size.width * 0.045, weight: .semibold, design: .default)).offset(y: 2)
                    Image("Label2").resizable().frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.15, height: 15, alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                    
                }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: geo.size.height * 0.7).background(Color.black).offset(y: -5)
            }
            
            GeometryReader { geo in
                HStack(spacing: geo.size.width * 0.1 / 7) {
    
                    Link(destination: deeplinkURLFirst) {
                        ZStack {
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).foregroundColor(mainColor).frame(width: iconSize, height: iconSize)
                            
                            Image(base64String:"")?.resizable().frame(width: iconSize, height: iconSize)
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                                .background(mainColor).cornerRadius(10)
                        }.frame(width: iconSize, height: iconSize)
                    }
                    Link(destination: deeplinkURLFirst) {
                        ZStack {
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).foregroundColor(mainColor).frame(width: iconSize, height: iconSize)
                            
                            Image(base64String: "")?.resizable().frame(width: iconSize, height: iconSize)
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                                .background(mainColor).cornerRadius(10)
                        }.frame(width: iconSize, height: iconSize)
                    }

                    Link(destination: deeplinkURLFirst) {
                        ZStack {
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).foregroundColor(mainColor).frame(width: iconSize, height: iconSize)
                            
                            Image(base64String: "")?.resizable().frame(width: iconSize, height: iconSize)
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                                .background(mainColor).cornerRadius(10)
                        }.frame(width: iconSize, height: iconSize)
                    }

                    Link(destination: deeplinkURLFirst) {
                        ZStack {
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).foregroundColor(mainColor).frame(width: iconSize, height: iconSize)
                            
                            Image(base64String: "")?.resizable().frame(width: iconSize, height: iconSize)
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                                .background(mainColor).cornerRadius(10)
                        }.frame(width: iconSize, height: iconSize)
                    }
                    
                }.frame(width: .infinity, height: geo.size.height * 0.9, alignment: .leading).background(Color(red: 0.118, green: 0.118, blue: 0.15)).border(Color.white, width: 0).position(x: geo.size.width * 0.5, y: 20)
            }
            
            
            
        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity).background(Color(red: 0.118, green: 0.118, blue: 0.15)).onAppear {
            print("all good")
            
        }
    }
}

@main
struct WidgetTest: Widget {
    let kind: String = WIDGET_PROJECT_NAME

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        IntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: ConfigurationIntent.self, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            WidgetTestEntryView(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("Favourites")
        .description("Fast access to favoutires cagetory.")
        .supportedFamilies([.systemMedium])
    }
}

struct WidgetTest_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        WidgetTestEntryView(entry: SimpleEntry(date: Date(), configuration: ConfigurationIntent()))
            .previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemMedium))
    }
    
    
}


extension Image {
    init?(base64String: String) {
        guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: base64String, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) else { return nil }
        guard let uiImage = UIImage(data: data) else { return nil }
        self = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
    }
}
```

Comment: A suggestion? Change the title of your question. I was going to comment that SwiftUI doesn't use AutoLayout but I saw where you already know that. It's probably a language gap, but as is you question reads like you want to use AutoLayout in SwiftUI, not that you are having an issue related to padding of views in an `HStack`. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SwiftUI does the autolayout for you, it is different than UIKit you are supposed to support all screens at once, that is why the spacing changes but your can set "rules"

```
//Prevents the repeating of code
struct ImageView: View {
    var deeplinkURLFirst: URL
    let mainColor: Color
    //Add another parameter for the image info I counldn't reprodice that
    var body: some View {
        Link(destination: deeplinkURLFirst) {
            ZStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    .foregroundColor(mainColor)
                    .overlay(
                    //Keep image within rectangle bounds
                    //The systemName stuff is just to replicate an actual image fill in with your image code
                    Image(systemName: "square")
                    .resizable())
            }
        }
        //Rule
        //Keep the images squares or you can set frame using your iconSize 
        //for all but the size of an iPhone 7 or SE is not the same 
        //as a ProMax it is best to set a ratio
        //If you fix the size padding will have to give way to adjust for larger/smaller screens.
        .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)

    }
}
struct WidgetTestEntryView : View {
    //var entry: Provider.Entry //I am just working with the View itself not a widget
    var deeplinkURLFirst: URL {
        URL(string: "\("WIDGET_DEEP_LINK")0")!
    }
    let iconSize: CGFloat = 75.0
    var widgetLabel = "Favourites"
    let mainColor = Color(red: 0.218, green: 0.215, blue: 0.25)
    let setSpacing: CGFloat = 4
    var body: some View {
        //Having multiple of GeometryReader just adds to the confusion look at the View as a whole vs pieces
        //Less is more with SwiftUI it is meant to support multiple screens
        //Set simple rules
        GeometryReader { geo in
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
                //Top portion
                HStack(spacing: geo.size.width * 0.4){
                    Text(widgetLabel).foregroundColor(.white).font(.system(size: geo.size.width * 0.045, weight: .semibold, design: .default))
                    //The systemName stuff is just to replicate an actual image fill in with your image code
                    Image(systemName: "square").resizable().foregroundColor(.white)
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.15, height: 15, alignment: .center)
                }
                //Using to many of these will end up causing conflicts
                //SwiftUI does a lot of the work for you
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: geo.size.height * (1/3))
                //Rule:
                //This will set the space between the boxes
                HStack(spacing: setSpacing)
                {
                    //Add another parameter for the image info I counldn't reproduce that without data
                    ImageView(deeplinkURLFirst: deeplinkURLFirst, mainColor: mainColor)
                    ImageView(deeplinkURLFirst: deeplinkURLFirst, mainColor: mainColor)
                    ImageView(deeplinkURLFirst: deeplinkURLFirst, mainColor: mainColor)
                    ImageView(deeplinkURLFirst: deeplinkURLFirst, mainColor: mainColor)
                }
                //Rule:
                //Keep the edge of the boxes from the edge of the screen/HStack
                //It is just a minimum so this will give if the space requries it to maintain ratio and spacing between boxes
                .padding(setSpacing)
                
                //This might need adjusting but the % of the top + the % of the bottom should == 1
                .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height * (2/3), alignment: .center)
                //This color needs to be adjusted to the right Color
                .background(Color(UIColor.darkGray))
            }
        }
        .background(Color(red: 0.118, green: 0.118, blue: 0.15))
        //Just to simualte widget size without crating a widget you shouldn't need it in your actual code
        .frame(maxWidth: 350, maxHeight: 150)
        .cornerRadius(20)
        .onAppear {
            print("all good")
            
        }
    }
}
```